# How can I structure Firestore to store history of events that can easily be accessed?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have been continuously changing my database structure and just can't find a good solution.

My database stores habits, each document is a different habit. The fields of the habits hold information on the habit, but where I am struggling is how to structure the completion/history.

Unlike a task, a habit is completed over and over again which means I need to store all that information and be able to query it easily for date ranges and such.

**First**
The first idea I had was a subcollection of documents that each held information such as the date, the completion status, etc.

Although this idea sounds good the problem was querying. I am using flutter and inside a StreamBuilder it proved difficult to access a sub-collection.

[image: First]

**Second**
My second idea was to use a document field in the habit. With this, I could have an array called completed, and the array would store a Map with the date, the status, etc.

With this idea, I made it the furthest, but where I struggle is changing the status of one field in the Map in the array.

[image: Second]

**Third**
My third and most recent idea I haven't made much headway with yet but I was thinking I could use a nest Maps in the habits document field. A field called history would be equivalent to the map, then inside the Map, a date in string format would be equivalent to the Map that stores all the essential information.

This idea was great in a lot of ways, but querying the data by date range when the date is in a string format will inevitably be difficult.

[image: Third]

Which of these structures is more ideal, or is there a better way to do it? The language I am using is Flutter so I need to operate within the guidelines of the cloud_firestore package.

Comment: Without knowing how you intend to query your data, it's not possible to say what's idea.  The ideal structure is the one that suits your intended queries and works within the limits of Cloud Firestore.

Comment: With your second approach, where did you struggle to update a habit? You could use a where query to return the habit you want.

Comment: Well it’s hard to say because if it was a sub collection I would need to query a second time with a listener, but with it being a field it would have been in the first query. I want to be able to access data in a specific date range, which was easy with the array of maps utilizing the .where functionality. The problem was updating data in the array. And with the map of maps I guess I can do it all by date ranges will be difficult with the field for the date being a string.

Comment: This is in response to noodles the second was great for querying what I want. I could use where and specify date ranges and attribute values to narrow it down. But changing the field morning from false to true in one of the maps wasn’t working well since it’s all in an array. I would have needed to remove the whole map, then add it back in to the array. At least that’s what I gathered from similar questions.

Comment: Hi Anthony, turns out I'm currently working on a similar habit tracking app with firestore, and I am facing this issues. This is 2 years later but were you able to sort it out?